# Combine two POSTs using global variables

Tags: php, post, scope, submit, global

I would like to combine two POSTs in PHP like this:

```
... some HTML (first submit button) ...

<?

if(isset($_POST['ChooseMatchday'])) {
    $GLOBALS['match'] = ... // assign some values to the array $GLOBALS['match']
    echo count($GLOBALS['match']); // output: some number > 0
}

?>

... some HTML  (second submit button) ...

<?

if(isset($_POST['WriteToDB'])){
    echo count($GLOBALS['match']); // output: 0
}

?>
```

Why aren't there any values in `$GLOBALS['match']` in the second case?

When the user hit's the first submit button, the values in `$GLOBALS['match']` should be set.
When the user hit's the second submit button, the values in `$GLOBALS['match']` should be written into a database.
What am I doing wrong? Is there any other good way to realize this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Global variables are just within a single script invocation. If you want variables that persist between invocations, use session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to look at the life-span of the script
When the user hits

First button: 
   Form submitted
   script runs (sets your variable)
   script terminates (as does all things related)

Second button: 
   Form submitted
   script runs (does not set second variable)
   script terminates (as does all things related)

What you will likely want to do is set a 'hidden' form field.
You can also deal with SESSION http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php but that is a whole nother bag-o-monkeys